# Why has the total area of polygon been reduced after using the splitting tool in QGIS 3.16.6?

Tags: qgis-3, area, splitting, shape-area

[image]I am using the splitting tool to split an original polygon (survey boundary) into smaller polygons (vegetation types).

When I sum the total area of the shapefile after splitting (all the veg types) it is less than the area of the original polygon by 0.1 ha (100.61ha vs 100.71 ha).

Is this avoidable as it creates issues when reporting on the data. As I have only split the original polygon into component parts I would assume the total would be the same.

P.S. It has made me wonder if it is an artefact of the boundaries resulting from the splitting. i.e. do the boundaries take up 'space' resulting in less total area in the survey area.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware I did rollback prev. edits sorry. I made an edit regarding the post script.

Comment: How do you split the polygon, based on what? If you use another layer for it: do both have the same CRS? Without further information, one could just speculate.

Comment: That may have been it, it wasn't intentional

Comment: Boundaries do not take space. Polygons are defined based on rings (closed lines) that are created from a sequence of vertices.

Comment: @Babel Thanks for the feedback. Both layers have the same CRS. I have the original layer and then the second layer (split into parts) that was based on the original layer.

My GIS vocabulary is limited sorry so ill try my best to be clear.

Comment: Providing sample data and/or screenshot could help understanding the problem. How do you calculate area?

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the Statistics tool I was using to get the area

Comment: I use the 'Split Features' tool to split the original survey area polygon. I am wondering if it could be an artefact of how many decimal places are used in generating area.

Comment: Rounding error is what I was thinking about, too. However, would be strange to have the first digit change, but not the second one: 100.61 vs 100.71. What CRS is your data in? Can you provide sample data to test?